# Check if the offline map available

Tags: here-api

I am working on an Android app with Here map sdk, and the MapLoader works fine for me to manage the offline maps, but in case of no network connection, how can I check if a specific map is installed or not ? Because in such case, the app can not retrieve the package lists anymore. Can the app check the device directly instead?

many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is currently a limitation of the MapLoader API. It requires a data connection to retrieve the latest catalog. One suggestion is to store / serialize the MapPackageSelection in the application so you can keep the installation state.

Comment: thanks!  If the app uninstalled and reinstalled again, the offline map should still be there , right ?

Comment: Generically yes. Only exception is if you used the isolated disk cache API [1] and set the diskcache to be the private folder of your application. [1] https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/map-service.html)